# Unity fails after upgrade 14.04 -> 15.05 and installing nvidia drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 15.04

So, I was running Ubuntu 14 LTS more or less happily (nvidia drivers were working fine with unity and all).
Then the upgrade manager asked if I wanted to upgrade to 14.10. I did the upgrade and everything worked fine. Then it asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 15.04 vivid. *Sure! What can possibly go wrong...*

After the update I was stuck in a login loop. From vivid to livid. I resolved that by manually installing the latest nvidia drivers.
Now I can login and run programs but Unity is just not working.

If I try to run unity from the terminal, I get two suspicious error messages:

- something about Upstart

  ```
  stop: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist
  compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
  compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
  start: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist
  ```
- something about OpenGL

  ```
  compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.
  ```

I tried:

1. reinstalling the nvidia drivers via purging
2. resetting the compiz profile
3. reinstalling via purging ubuntu-desktop/compiz/unity
4. booting with Upstart: it replaces the Upstart error with "service unity-panel-bla unknown" or something like that. The openGL error is still there.

Now this is getting very annoying. I would just like to let unity know that it can use openGL just fine and get on with my life.
Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem only arose because I had a custom Compiz profile in the old system and after the upgrade it got silently deleted so Unity could not find it and just crashed with no indication as of the source of the failure.

Importing my settings to a profile under the old name using `ccsm` solved the issue.

And this is year 2015.

Comment: @Bordaiborl please, could you describe all the commands and steps you did to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot in fail safe mode as root and then   remove compiz with `apt-get purge compiz` and the install it again with `apt-get install compiz ubuntu-desktop unity`

Comment: nope, still exactly the same problem. I tried reinstalling all the related packages a hundred times. No progress